# Convert date format is not working when passing a field in SQL

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion, date-format

In my SQL query `CONVERT(varchar,getDate(),0)` is working => 19 june 2022 10.30AM
But `CONVERT(varchar,il.DepartureStation,0)` is not working and it gives 2022-09-21 22:20:00.0.

Do I need to convert the il.DepartureStation to date?

Thank you

Comment: What data type is DepartureStation? is it varchar or some kind of date data type? please edit your question an add this information.

Comment: I guess by "not working" you mean you would like the result to be in the same format as the first example